# Publishing gem https://rubygems.org

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I am trying to build a cli ruby gem. Everything is ready, just need to publish it.

First I tried this,

```
Enter your RubyGems.org credentials.                                                                                                                               
Don't have an account yet? Create one at https://rubygems.org/sign_up                                                                                              
   Email:   hima.chhag@gmail.com                                                                                                                                   
Password:                                                                                                                                                          

Signed in.                                                                                                                                                         
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::FormatError)                                                                                                        
    No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - popular_deals-0.1.0.gem
```

and got an error, so after doing some research I got to know that I need to make gem first,

So did this ..

```
 gem build popular_deals-0.1.0.gem                                                                                                                             
ERROR:  Gemspec file not found: popular_deals-0.1.0.gem                                                                                                            
[19:14:21] (master) popular-deals-from-slickdeals.net-cli
```

But, still getting errors, am I missing anything? what should I do to solve "    ERROR:  Gemspec file not found: popular_deals-0.1.0.gem                                                                                                            " error? I do have "popular_deals.gemspec"

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: can you go to your gem's main directory, run `ls -R` and post the results in your question? i need to see your folder structure so i can help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @eiko.. Thank you so much for trying to help me. But this problem is solved. It was my I need to build gem with my gemspec file. So, the command gem build pupular_deals.gemspec worked! Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem, glad to hear you figured it out c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved. It was my fault, I needed to build gem with my gemspec file. So, the command gem build pupular_deals.gemspec worked!

Comment: Yeah, it's `.gemspec` -> `.gem`, so you can't build a `.gem`. That's what *is* built. They should really add a message to handle this case as it can be confusing.